# NSPredicate 101: Using NSPredicate with a NSMutableArray of custom objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

This is a pretty basic question here, and even though I think understand the basics of NSPredicate, I'm still a little stumped as to why I'm getting an error here (searchText is a pointer to a NSString object that's being passed into the method).

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[cd] %@", searchText];
_searchResults = [_personArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

I have a NSMutableArray of custom objects (e.g., Person objects), which have a name property. All I'm trying to do is use a NSPredicate to filter potential matches when the user begins typing in a UISearchBar. The IB component is straightforward enough and appears to function just fine. When I attempt to search and begin filtering however, the basic application crashes with the following error:

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[xPerson isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8043340'`

My understanding is the predicate will be passed to each object in the NSMutableArray, with the SELF keyword in the predicate referring to the respective object (and which, I believe, isn't even really necessary in this case), and the .name being able to use the synthesized property on the custom object. The error seems to suggest the -isEqualToString: call is being called on the custom object and not the object's property.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try it like this,

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", searchText];
_searchResults = [_personArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: This was actually something I had tried after rummaging around on some of SO's other related threads on this topic, but I still get that same error verbatim. 

Given that the custom class is a bare bones, typical class using the default, auto-synthesized properties (which is indeed 'name'), the NSPredicate's syntax should be correct in either scenario. 

I did notice that if I change 'contains' to 'like' in the predicate, it works correctly (although I don't get any results back, it at least doesn't throw an exception). Why exactly that is, I don't know. 

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: I have almost the same thing in my app and it works perfectly for me with the above code. So I am not sure if the issue is with Predicate here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The error wasn't in the precicate,but in the cell of the table view.
I was setting the cell like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I forgot to make the Object parse.Then I changed the code to this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = ((Product*)[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).name;
```

So,maybe your erros isn't in the NSPredicate too.